# Elastic Search exists query works the other way around

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using elastic search version 5.6.1 and I have an issue with the `exists` query in elastic search.

Say I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "Something",
  "svg": "<svg xmlns=...</svg>"
}
```

I would expect a query that checks for the existence of the svg field would return this document:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {"exists": {"field": "svg"}}
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't.

Though it does return documents with the value `"svg": ""`, which is expected behavior.

The following query **does** return the document and that seems to be an upside down world to me.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {"exists": {"field": "svg"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Though this one does return documents with the a `null` value in the svg field.

So the first query returns documents with an empty string in the svg field, and the second query returns documents with a valid svg string and with null values. So I cannot just use a hack to use it the other around either.

Am I missing something here? Am I using it in the wrong way? Because this is confusing me a lot.
Anything I could do to get the expected results?

Comment: Can you post your mapping for the index?  Or at least for the svg field?  Running your queries w/ your sample record in a quick test index worked as expected for me (empty+value in must results, null in must_not results).

Comment: The problem was indeed in the mapping. First my search was different and the svg was never searched on, so I had turned indexing off. Turning it on fixed it. Thank you!